# ng-table how to get data form API AWS using angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-web-services

I am working on Angular 5 and ng-table but how to get data from API using AWS?
I am not getting any errors. I can retrieve data on console but the table is not filled with data.

I am using this code as follows:
participants.ts

```
 private data: Array<Participant> = [];
 public constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private 
 participantsListService: ParticipantListService) {
 this.length = this.data.length;
 }
public ngOnInit(): void {
this.getJsonData().subscribe(itemsFromGetRequest => {
  // Loop through the items for the HTTP GET request and insert them 
into the data array (the table).
  itemsFromGetRequest.forEach(item => {
    this.data.push(item);
    this.length = this.data.length; // this is for pagination
    this.onChangeTable(this.config);
  });
  });
  }

  public getJsonData(): Observable<any[]> {
  const myHeader = new HttpHeaders();
  return this.httpClient.get<Participant[]>('url here',
  {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', '77777')})
  .map((response) => {
   this.data = response; // Here the table is filled with data.
      console.log(this.data);
      return this.data;
  },
   error => console.log('error', error)
  );
  }
```